# undertow webserver not binding to remote address

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, undertow, nio2

I'm testing out the undertow 2.0.0.Alpha1 webserver. When I run it locally it works and returns `Hello World` when I go to `localhost:80`. I then deploy the webserver on a remote server and go to `remote_ip:80` but I get no response back. If I run `curl -i -X GET http://localhost:80` on the remote server then I get `Hello World` back as well. So the server is definitely running but for some reason it's just not accessible via the remote ip address. If I try to set a hostname as the remote IP in the code (i.e. `.addHttpListener(80, "remote.ip")`) then I get a `BindException`.

```
import io.undertow.Undertow;
import io.undertow.server.HttpHandler;
import io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class HelloWorldServer {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sudo fuser -k 80/tcp");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(HelloWorldServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        Undertow server = Undertow.builder()
                .addHttpListener(80, null)
                .setHandler(new HttpHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void handleRequest(final HttpServerExchange exchange) throws Exception {
                        exchange.getResponseSender().send("Hello World");
                    }
                }).build();
        server.start();
    }

}
```

Any clues?

Comment: Clue #1: use "netstat -a" (or equivalent) to check what IP and port the server is listening on.

Comment: `tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:80            :::*                    LISTEN      2939/java       
`

Comment: So are you using curl on IPv6 using that IP address?  (It is "localhost" ...)

Comment: No I think `localhost` is just linked to `127.0.0.1` by default on Ubuntu

Answer (score 6):

The second argument on `addHttpListener(80, null)` is the host. You need to put a host name or IP in there to have it listen on the public IP. Using `null` it will only bind to localhost.

Try binding to the public IP or binding to `0.0.0.0` if you want to bind to all addresses.

```java
Undertow server = Undertow.builder()
        .addHttpListener(80, "0.0.0.0")
        .setHandler(new HttpHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handleRequest(final HttpServerExchange exchange) throws Exception {
                exchange.getResponseSender().send("Hello World");
            }
        }).build();
server.start();
```